# Aspose word Document don't want to use the print method

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, document, aspose

I can see in the Aspose documentation that we can use a method Print on an aspose document (https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/document/methods/print)

So I create my Aspose Document and a document builder to write something on the document.
After that I try to use the print method, but they told me that this method doesn't exist.

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.Writeln("TEST");
doc.Print();
```

I try to choose directly a word document that I have on my PC, but that is the same problem. Do you know why I can't use this Print method ? Or Maybe how can I add this method by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that printing feature of Aspose.Words for .NET is not available in .NET Standard, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac API. You can use Document.Print method using .NET Framework.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.